# Consequences of mismatching Display name between Facebook iOS SDK and Facebook App Dashboard

Tags: ios, facebook

In the Facebook documentation it states we should set the Display Name of our Facebook App, either by an entry into the plist with a key of `FacebookDisplayName` or by manually setting it on the Facebook SDK (`setDisplayName:` on `FBSDKSettings`)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#4--configure-your-info-plist

I am changing the name of my app. I have currently got previous versions of the app that use the Facebook Display Name `App Name 1`. I would like to change the name of the Facebook app to `App Name 2`. This means currently live apps will be using the wrong `FacebookDisplayName`.

I cannot find any documentation on what the effect of setting display name programmatically in the app actually is; it appears to do nothing.

What happens when the Facebook App name changes in the Facebook App Dashboard but old apps are using the old name?